# Memory Leak: Issues with releasing NSArray in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsarray

I have a code which shows leaks in Instruments. It shows leaks where I initialize the `arrayDetPerformance` with the contents of `arrayDetail`

If I release my `arrayDetail` then my app crashes.

What could be wrong?

Here is the code:

```
    NSDictionary *finalResult = [extractUsers JSONValue];
    //      NSLog(@" Stamp-16 : %@",[NSDate date]);
    NSLog(@"Array2  : %d",[arrayDetail retainCount]);        //RETAIN COUNT IS 0
    arrayDetail = [[finalResult objectForKey:@"Detail"]
    NSLog(@"Array2  : %d",[arrayDetail retainCount]);       //RETAIN COUNT IS 2

    //  NSLog(@"Data is : %@",array1);
    //      NSLog(@" Stamp-17 : %@",[NSDate date]);

    //NSLog(@"Final Value is : %@",[[allUsers objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"password"]);

    //[self setUserData:allUsers];
    //[tblView reloadData];

    [responseString release];
    [request release];

}



//sleep(0.3);
//[inProgressIndicator stopAnimating];
[fileContents release];

//Release all the allocated data
[json release];
//label.text = @"Finish";
//  NSLog(@" Stamp-19 : %@",[NSDate date]);
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//NSLog(@"Array2  : %d",[array2 retainCount]);

arrayDetPerformance = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayDetail];
chartPoints= [arrayDetPerformance valueForKey:@"Points"];
NSLog(@"Chart Points: %@",chartPoints);
[def setObject:chartPoints forKey:@"yarray"];
[def setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"flagThumb"];

//array1 = [[NSMutableArray  alloc] initWithObjects:@"New",@"Table",@"View",nil];
//[self.Dettable reloadData];
//sNSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
//[array2 release];
NSLog(@"ArrayDEtPerfomance : %d",[arrayDetPerformance retainCount]);
NSLog(@"array2 : %d",[arrayDetail retainCount]);
if([chartPoints count]>0)
{
    PlotItem *plotItem = [[PlotGallery sharedPlotGallery] objectAtIndex:0];
    [plotItem imageHive:Fund];
}

//[arrayDetail release];

}
```

Memory leak is shown on the line

```
arrayDetPerformance = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayDetail];
```

Also I am confused on why the retain count directly goes from 0 to 2 in the below code:

```
NSLog(@"Array2  : %d",[arrayDetail retainCount]);        //RETAIN COUNT IS 0
    arrayDetail = [[finalResult objectForKey:@"Detail"]
NSLog(@"Array2  : %d",[arrayDetail retainCount]);       //RETAIN COUNT IS 2
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: How is `arrayDetPerformance` declared? Is it a property?

Comment: Side comment: AFAIK you should never rely on [yourObj retainCount] value in run-time... Retain count can only be sth useful in Instruments.

Comment: @Nick Weaver: Yeah it is a NSMutableArray with property (nonatomic,retain) and is synthesized. What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you setting `arrayDetPerformance` like in your code shown or are you actually using `self.arrayDetPerformance = ...`?

Comment: -retainCount can **never return zero**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows a leak because you allocate `arrayDetPerformance` and then not release it. Simple as that. At least that's what we can tell from the code you are showing us.

As for the rest, don't use `retainCount` to debug memory problems, ever! You have to understand the simple [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) and follow them, nothing else. Since you don't know what Apple's underlying code does, you cannot rely on the retain count of an object.

As to your question relating to this code:

```
NSLog(@"Array2  : %d",[arrayDetail retainCount]);        //RETAIN COUNT IS 0
arrayDetail = [[finalResult objectForKey:@"Detail"]
NSLog(@"Array2  : %d",[arrayDetail retainCount]);       //RETAIN COUNT IS 2
```

You are assigning a whole other object to `arrayDetail` so it's completely meaningless to compare any properties of `arrayDetail` before and after the assignment. The retain count could be all over the place and it would not tell you anything.

I get the impression that you don't really know what you are doing here. You should read the memory management rules again and again until you understand them thoroughly.

Comment: @PARTH: so maybe when dealloc gets called and tries to release arrayDetPerformance before you even use it, so it was never initialized/allocated?

Answer (score 1):

**`retainCount` won't help you debug your problem** (in fact it will almost never be relevant to debugging, so best forget it's even there).

Don't release `arrayDetail`, as you don't own it. The problem is with `arrayDetPerformance`. You're allocing an object on that line, and it's not being released anywhere. Now, you may be doing that elsewhere in your code, but if you aren't, send it a `release` when you've finished using it.

**Edit**

If you're deallocating `arrayDetPerformance` in your `dealloc` method, I'm assuming it's an instance variable? In this case, you can't assume that it doesn't already point at an object, so you should send it a `release` before assigning it to the new object.

Alternatively, if it is configured as a property, just use `self.arrayDetPerformance = ...` which will take care of the memory management for you.

Comment: I already deallocate my arrayDetPerformance in my dealloc method so what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

## Do not call retainCount

`retainCount` is useless.  The absolute retain count of an object is an implementation detail.   The rule is simple;   if you cause something to be retained, you must cause it to be released when you are done with it.  End of story.

The [memory management documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) discusses this fully.

---

First, `retainCount` can *never return zero*.   The only time you'll get a zero is if you happened to message `nil`.   This:

```
NSLog(@"Array2  : %d",[arrayDetail retainCount]);        //RETAIN COUNT IS 0
arrayDetail = [[finalResult objectForKey:@"Detail"]
NSLog(@"Array2  : %d",[arrayDetail retainCount]);       //RETAIN COUNT IS 2
```

You are causing `arrayDetail` to point to a different object on that second line.   Thus, no relation between the retain count before/after that line.

When leaks tells you a leak is on a particular line like this one...

```
arrayDetPerformance = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayDetail];
```

... it is telling you that said object allocated on that line was leaked.  It is **not** telling you that particular line was the cause of the leak.   The leak is likely because you either over-retained it somewhere else or forgot to leak it.

You've said in several comments that you are "deallocating [something] in your dealloc".  Show your dealloc method's implementation.

Comment: I nearly searched for another answer of yours to cut and paste that first paragraph! :)

Answer (score -1):

[arrayDetPerformance release]; is not written in your code;

So, its show memory leak.